# Multiple function load on ajax scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have the following js for [infinite ajax scroll](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/)

```
jQuery.ias().on('rendered', function(items) {   
        SOME_FUCNTION();            
        alert("Some_function!");                
    });
SOME_FUCNTION()
{
 jQuery('.button').click(function() {       
     alert('You just clicked the button');      
 });
}
```

Now, it shows 10 posts every infinite scroll load.

However, I realized that every time it loads a new set of items, it runs the function again on the whole page and the function "accumulates" (I get the alert every time a new set is loaded).

**EDIT**

For example, the first div container at the top of the page has a button, which shows an alert("You just clicked the button") when clicked.

Now, let say the infinite ajax scroll loaded 3 times (so, total 30 posts so far).

Then, when I click the same first button, now it shows the alert three times as if the function was accumulated three times.

How do I fix this? Any suggestions?

Comment: can you share Some_function() or simply append and don't run on whole page

Comment: what is the expected behavior...!

Comment: I added an example above and a sample function.